# How to identify and replace an unfamiliar character from a file?

Tags: c#, unicode

There's a character in a text file supplied to my software that I cannot read back out.

I can't even paste this character into the browser to search for it - it just inserts a white space.

If I read this text file's contents, the character comes out as '\f', which is a form feed character.

Notepad shows a bold up arrow. Other text editors (Sublime) shows an unrecognized symbol.

How can I find out what character this is?

Comment: Some characters aren't printable.

Comment: @Amy Notepad successfully prints the character. Other editors like Sublime do not.

Comment: open it in a binary editor and look up the hex value

Comment: If this were a formfeed, Notepad wouldn’t be able to show it as such and would probably substitute in a weird graphical character like a bold upwards-pointing arrow (what you saw) or (what I’ve seen more commonly) a stylized person of some sort

Comment: @dlatikay Did this in VS 2015, shows `0C`(zero C)

Comment: That’s a form feed, all right. Pretty much every character set has all the bytes which start with a 0 bit (first hex digit between 0 and 7 inclusive) the same as ASCII.

Comment: Files, and inputs in general, consist of *bytes*. By their very nature, they *don't* have an encoding that you can discover. Encodings are ways for you to *interpret* sequences of bytes. But the two are, inherently, *not* tied together or discoverable.

Comment: originally an instruction understood by line printers. whitespace on screen, feed to next form (or page) on that kinds of printers that are more on-topic at retrocomputing SE

Comment: Thanks all, I can look for a `'\f'`occurrence in the input, and remove as needed.

Comment: Terminology police: If it wasn't a Unicode character, `StreamReader` wouldn't pass it; `String` couldn't hold it.

Comment: @TomBlodget good point. I'll rephrase it if you have a suggestion on a title.

Comment: Based on your comment to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43053328/2226988), I think you are trying to "Identify and replace an unfamiliar character from a file"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was

> How can I find out what character set this is from?

ASCII.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed)

To answer the question of why it does not display... think of it as a command.  When a printer(for example) sees a form feed, it advances the page by 1.
You cannot see it in your editor because per @dlatikay :

> notepad renders it as ↑ because that's a visual cue for "feed paper
>   until first line of next page

Comment: This is not an answer to how you can find out; it is an answer to what the character set is. And it doesn’t actually help because there is no indication of why you think it’s ASCII (although I agree it is), what to do about that, or why it is displaying weirdly.

Comment: Marking this as answer after the edit. It is a form feed character. I can detect it in code by doing something like: `if (contents.IndexOf('\f') >= 0)`

Comment: i like @Damien_The_Unbeliever 's answer above.  But this is the general idea.

Comment: the statement "you cannot see it in your editor because it is not a displayable character" is confusing. IMHO notepad renders it as ↑ because that's a visual cue for "feed paper until first line of next page".

Comment: Ok, I have retracted the downvote. Now please remove the "apologies" from the answer.

Comment: It's what I get for being a lazy programmer.... Wait, that's redundant.